# Keyword search limited to specific post type filtered by multiple custom taxonomies?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, search

Is it possible to limit a search for keywords to a specific post type (say 'news') but filter the results by selected custom taxonomies?

- I have a news section.
- This has the custom post type called 'news'.
- This then has the custom taxonomy 'news-category'.
- There are several custom taxonomy terms that need to be listed with
  checkboxes next to them.

Say for instance someone wants to search for the keyword "Wales" and they check the custom taxonomies "Medical" and "Financial", then it displays the results by those search queries.

To sum up, they are only searching within the news post type which is filtered by the custom taxonomies and keyword. Is this possible? If so, how?

---

UPDATE:

I have a template called archive-members.php with the following, how can I wrap all this with the necessary code to show a search with keyword+category, just keyword or just category.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Default_Theme
 */

get_header();
?>

        <!-- Main Content -->

        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <div class="entry">

                <div class="left-search">
                    <div class="page-title-search">
                        <h2>Search</h2>
                        <form id="custom-search" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get">
                        <?php //Get all (non-empty) terms for taxonomy 'news-category'
                        $args = array('orderby' => 'name','order' => 'ASC');
                        $categories = get_terms( 'members', $args );
                        ?>
                        <!-- Visible input for search term -->
                        <p style="margin-bottom:5px!IMPORTANT;"><b>Keyword</b></p>
                        <input type="text" class="keyword" name="s" value="" />
                        <div class="clear"></div>

                        <p style="margin-top:20px!IMPORTANT;margin-bottom:2px!IMPORTANT;"><b>Specialisms</b></p>
                        <?php //Display checkbox for each term
                        $counter = 1;
                        foreach ($categories as $category) {
                            echo '<input type="checkbox" id="field-'.$counter.'" class="mycheckbox" name="mw-filter-terms[]" value="'.$category->slug.'">';
                            echo '<label for="field-'.$counter.'" class="mycheckbox-label">'.esc_html($category->name).'</label>';
                        $counter++; 
                        } ?>

                        <!-- Hidden input to set post type to news-->
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="members" />

                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <!-- Submit button -->
                        <button class="blue medium awesome awesomeforward awesomesearch" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>                     


                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="news-content" style="background-color:#ececec!IMPORTANT;">
                    <div class="page-title-content">
                        <h2>Members Directory</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="news-content-inner">
                        <div class="inner-holder">
                            <?php the_field('content', 1886); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                            <a class="blue medium awesome awesomeforward" style="margin-left:193px;margin-bottom:10px;color: white !important; " href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/member-signup/">Become A Member</a>                    

                <div class="news-content" style="background-color:#ececec!IMPORTANT;">
                    <div class="page-title-content">
                        <h2>Search Results</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="news-content-inner">
                        <?php $portfolioloop1 = new WP_Query( array( 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'members', 'posts_per_page' => 300 ) ); ?>
                        <?php while ( $portfolioloop1->have_posts() ) : $portfolioloop1->the_post(); ?>
                        <div <?php if (get_field('logo') != "") { ?>style="height:120px;"<?php } ?> class="news-item" onclick="location.href='<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>'">
                            <?php if (get_field('logo') != "") { ?>
                                <div style="height:110px;float:left;">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td height="110">
                                    <img style="margin-right:15px;" src="<?php echo the_field('logo'); ?>" width="150" alt="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" />
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <div <?php if (get_field('logo') != "") { ?>style="float:left;width:379px;"<?php } ?>>
                                <h2><a style="color:#AA3CA7!important;" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                <p class="news-page">
                                    <?php $description = get_field('description');
                                    echo substr($description,0,300) . "..." ?>
                                </p>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

                    </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>                   
            </div>
        </div>    

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Not really an exact answer, but this might also help you out a bit more: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/searching-with-multiple-tags-using-checkboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly inefficient to use `query_posts` and I often find it's more trouble than it's worth. Instead, to set the post type you can just have a hidden input inside the form with name 'post_type' and value (in this example) 'news'. WordPress handles the rest.

Unfortunately it is not so easy with taxonomies (maybe I've missed a trick?). However, rather than redo-ing the search with `query_posts`, you can just use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter which runs before the database is queried to filter by taxonomy term.

**The following assumes your news category has name 'news-category' and your post type is 'news':**

(First remember to remove your `query_posts` stuff from the search template - as this just over-rides the default query WordPress performs).

#### HTML markup

This is the form that displays your search:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<?php
 //Get all (non-empty) terms for taxonomy 'news-category'
 $args = array('orderby' => 'name','order' => 'ASC');
 $categories = get_terms( 'news-category', $args );

 //Display checkbox for each term
 foreach ($categories as $category) {
       echo '<input type="checkbox" name="my-filter-terms[]" value="'.$category->slug.'">'.esc_html($category->name);
  }
  ?>

    <!-- Hidden input to set post type to news-->
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="news" />

    <!-- Visible input for search term -->
    <input type="text" name="s" value="" />

    <!-- Submit button -->
    <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

I've used `my-filter-terms` to store the array of slugs of the checked terms. (It would probably be better to register a custom variable, but I'll leave that for now. I had hoped to be able to use the default taxonomy query variable but it didn't seem to work).

#### Filter the Search

The post type and search term will be automatically handled. The following is to filter by taxonomy term. This goes in your theme's functions.php:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','my_filter_the_search',10,1);
function my_filter_the_search($query){

    //If the query is a search AND taxonomy terms are set, filter by those terms:
    if($query->is_search() && isset($_GET['my-filter-terms'])){
        //Get array of slugs of checked terms
        $terms = (array) $_GET['my-filter-terms'];

        //Tax_query array
        $tax_query = array(array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'news-category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $terms,
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                )); 

        //Tell the query to filter by tax
        $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query  );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

The operator is set to `IN`. This means it searches any posts in any one of the checked terms. You could set it to `AND` to search posts which are in all the checked terms.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comprehensive answer, really appreciate it. It looks as though it's working as intended, the only thing I need to do is output the results - as it goes to a page not found at the moment. http://www.mediwales.com/v3/news/ How do I output the correct results? What template does it use?

Comment: Hi Rob, this is because your are posting the search to `/v3/news` rather than `/v3` (which I assume is where WordPress is installed...? Either way, testing with something like `.../v3?post_type=news&s=test` seems to correctly display the results. You may read [this codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) on search pages. In particular the template `search.php` (if present is used to display the results).

Comment: I also recommend using [`get_search_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form). In which case put the above HTML mark-up inside a template file called `searchform.php`

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the help, I just added <?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/ to the action of the form and that directs it to the right page. So it's just a case of repeating this for the events and opportunities and I'm done. I'll leave the bounty for now just in case I've missed anything but you've answered everything so thanks once again. (you'll 100% be getting the bounty!!)

Comment: Hi Stephen. I've just noticed that the search isn't quite working. Working on this page -  http://www.mediwales.com/v3/members/ . If you search for the keyword "teamworks" it shows the correct result. But if you search for just the category "business support" without putting in a keyword it just shows all the members. I'm using the code you posted.

Comment: Hi Rob - that's because if there is no search query set then WordPress doesn't think its a search. You could remove the `$query->is_search()`. Then a 'blank search' with 'business support' selected should show you the 'business support' (taxonomy-term) archive page.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I've removed that but it still shows all the members rather than just the category selected.

Comment: I've updated my question with more code. Think it's down to the template rather than anything the search is doing. What can I add to the code to incorporate the different search results?

Comment: You have used `$query` variable in your function params. Is it a global variable?

Comment: No, it's passed to the function hooked onto the `pre_get_posts` hook. Generally speaking though one instance of the `pre_get_posts` hook will correspond to the `global $wp_query` - but the vast majority will not. You can check if it corresponds to that global with `$query->is_main_query()`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by combining the 'tax_query' and 's' parameters of a WP_Query. I'm assuming here that you are using URL parameters to accomplish this, but you can set up the initial variables however you want.

```
$search_terms = isset( $_GET['s'] ) ? urldecode( $_GET['s'] ) : '';
$news_category = isset( $_GET['news_category'] ) ? urldecode( $_GET['news_category'] ) : '';


$query_args = array( 'post_type' => 'news', 'tax_query' => array() );

if ( !empty( $search_terms ) ) {
    $query_args['s'] = $search_terms;
}

if ( !empty( $search_terms ) ) {
    $query_args['tax_query'][] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'news',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $news_category
        )
    );
}

$my_posts = new WP_Query( $query_args );
if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) { // etc
```

More on WP_Query parameters, from the wordpress.org codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Whoops - that second `?` should be a `:`. I've edited the original accordingly.

Comment: Also, if you have not used WP_Query before, you might want to read a brief introduction to its use - http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/04/13/define-your-own-wordpress-loop-using-wp_query/ for instance. And I'm assuming that you have a method for creating the links in question; they would have the form of example.com/news/?s=searchterm&news_category=medical

Comment: I think I can get my head around the WP_Query part, that's just to display the necessary posts right? It's the creating the links I think I need more help on.

Comment: It's kind of a big job, but I can point you in the right direction. Your category links should be created something like this: `add_query_arg( 'news_category', $category_slug, $base_url );`, where the $base_url is whatever the underlying structure for the post archives is.

Comment: You may find it easier to use https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories, passing 'news_category' as the 'taxonomy' parameter. Actually, that might "just work" without any further customization.

Comment: I'll update my question with some code - I think I have what I need, I just can't tie the three elements together.

Comment: Your checkboxes need to be inside a `<form>` element - probably the same form as the search box would be fine. 
And make sure to finish out the WP_Query loop - what I've provided is partial, and will result in PHP errors.

Comment: Yep sorry, didn't update the code. That creates a url when you search - http://www.mediwales.com/v3/news/?cat=25&s=test Doesn't handle multiple categories though.

Comment: Oh dear, I'm well and truly stuck! I can't get it to output anything when submit is clicked.

Comment: You can't use `cat` as the name for your `<input>` checkboxes - that's reserved by WP_Query for categories, while you need a custom parameter for your custom taxonomy. Change it to `news_category[]` (the array brackets will allow for multiple values). And if you're getting a white screen, you'll want to check error logs/WP_DEBUG to get a sense of where the syntax error lives.